# Cannot run Xamarin app in debugger: NameNotFoundException: Xamarin.Android.Platform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've used Xamarin.Forms a few times but it was couple of months ago now. Installed Xamarin Studio and started a fresh Xamarin.Forms Solution. When I try to deploy it to the emulator i get this exception:

```
[AndroidRuntime] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_24 or Xamarin.Android.Platform!
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5856)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
[AndroidRuntime] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_24 or Xamarin.Android.Platform!
[AndroidRuntime]    at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:38)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5853)
[AndroidRuntime]    ... 10 more
[AndroidRuntime] Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Xamarin.Android.Platform
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfoAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:345)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:327)
[AndroidRuntime]    at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:32)
[AndroidRuntime]    ... 11 more
```

I'm running the app on an emulator with API level 25. I saw a solution here, presenting the option to hack the build and remove some file. I would really like to avoid that and just have a working automated build and deploy to emulator. Has anyone here seen this error before?

Comment: I got this too. I've not quite figured out the cause yet, but it seems to help to go into your project properties and deselect 'Use shared runtime'.

Comment: Do you have the SDK Platform for API 25 installed (this can be checked via the [SDK Manager](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/launch_sdk_manager/))? If so, try going to Project Properties > Build > General and set the Target framework to latest installed, then go to Android Application > Target Android version and set to “use target framework version”.